# Modal closes immediately

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, bootstrap-4

```html
<body onload="load_name();">
```

```html
<div class="product-side">
        <form>
            /*Blah blah*/
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Load_name:-

```js
$('#document').ready(function(){
        $('#form').submit(function(){
            $('#fin').modal();
        });
    });
```

Bootstrap Modal closes immediately when opened.
I have tried .modal('show') also.

Tell me if i should send full code.

Modal:-

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="fin" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Alert</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Logging Out...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="alert('work')">Ok</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I assume `.submit` forces the page to reload?

Comment: What is the goal of the `<form>`?

Comment: `.submit` reloads i made it to not reload by returning false and it worked @evolutionbox.

Comment: thanks. for the help